# Why my onclick getting called on each render in react js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, components, use-state

I am making a react application and on every render my variable gets changed even if the state change logic is inside a `onClick` function.

Here's my code:

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      options: [],
      suboptions: [],
      saveflag:false
    };
  }




 <div>
           {
             console.log(this.state.saveflag),
             saveflag?<></>:
             <button
            type="button"
            className="btn"
            onClick={() => this.props.data.handleApiGrants(apis),this.setState({saveflag:true})}
          >
            Save
          </button>}
        </div>
      </div>
```

Above I have set the flag saveflag to false initially and I want to change it on click of the save button but its getting changed on every render.

Can someone help?

Comment: you miss the parentheses around `() => this.props.data.handleApiGrants(apis),this.setState({saveflag:true})`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

preventDefault should help:

```html
onClick={e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.data.handleApiGrants(apis);
  this.setState({saveflag:true});
}}
```

Comment: Working now,Thanks

Comment: you don't need to add the preventDefault, its Unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem with syntax, now it will work:

```
onClick={() => {
            this.props.data.handleApiGrants(apis);
            this.setState({ saveflag: true });
          }}
```